# Merge a list elements with tuple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, tuples

I have a list and two tuples follows:

```
L1 = ['0.99999', '0.88888', '0.77777','0.66666','0.55555']

T1 = [('id_099', 'PND', '15.42'),
 ('id_088', 'PKZ', '16.04'),
 ('id_077', 'PZD', '16.73'),
 ('id_066', 'PNK', '18.19'),
 ('id_055', 'PNT', '10.62')]

T2 = [('XX13', 'XY13'),
 ('XX43', 'XY26'),
 ('XX77', 'XY13'),
 ('XX19', 'XY03'),
 ('XX93', 'XY13')]
```

I would like to merge each element array as a list or NumPy array in the following way

```
NEW = 
('id_099', 'PND', '15.42','0.99999','XX13', 'XY13'),
('id_088', 'PKZ','16.04','0.88888','XX77', 'XY13'),
.
.
.
```

When it was only tuples it was easy to merge them as follows:

```
merged = [i+j for i,j in zip(T1,T2)]
```

But I couldn't find an easy way to merge each element of a list with the tuples and it throws me an error when I try to apply the above method for the list.

> *TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple*

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide an example of lists that give an error? The values in `T1` and `T2` are merged correctly by zipping like you do

Comment: [i+(j,)+k for i,j,k in zip(T1,L1,T2)]`  - explicitly turn the middle element into a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) of modern (3.5+) Python, this isn't so hard:

```
merged = [(*i, x, *j) for i, x, j in zip(T1, L1, T2)]
```

The `tuple`s get unpacked with `*`, while the single element is just included normally in a `tuple` literal, no need to explicitly wrap the elements from `L1` in a `tuple`, nor perform multiple concatenations producing intermediate temporary `tuple`s.

Comment: Wow, nice answer.  And here I am monkeying around with `np.concatentate`.  This is way better, I'm not even going to post what I came up with.

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Times with `i+(x,)+j` are about the same.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @hpaulj: It's going to vary with implementation too; the older design (<=3.8 IIRC) would wrap the `x` in a one-`tuple` so a single instruction could treat all arguments alike to build the result; the newer (>=3.9) design uses per-item instructions similar to those used by listcomps (`LIST_APPEND` for single items, `LIST_EXTEND` for unpacked iterables, and a final instruction to convert from `list` to `tuple` when making a `tuple`). It's not necessarily more performant in all cases, but it scales better (the more stuff you're shoving in, the more concat overhead you avoid), and it's simpler.